# Profile Center link now required for transactional emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

I am attempting to build a transactional journey and was prompted with a message like this:

[image: Within Journey Builder]

Send classification is transactional, but it won't allow me to proceed.  Did the new update come with some new restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact Salesforce Support and ask them to disable the Profile Center links. Once this is in place you should no longer see this error message when trying to test/send.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put below snippet in your HTML body
**%%profile_center_url%%**

**Find the steps**
Insert personalization strings in Email Studio content or content from other apps.

1. Open the content you want to insert a personalization string.
2. Place your cursor where you want the personalization string to appear.
3. Enter the personalization string using the toolbar or type in the personalization string.

**Reference link**
[AMPScript here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)
[Personalization Strings steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_insert_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)

Comment: This was specific to a transactional send definition that does not inherently require those tags.